# Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls and Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles

Tags: c#, vb.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to programmatically (c#) upload  profile picture to sharepoint. I dont have sharepoint installed in my system. I came to know that Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls and Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles  dll's required to achieve it.

Now My question is can I include these dll's in a folder and just reference this to visual studio will they work for me  or installation of sharepoint is must ? Please help. Can any body provide any alternative solution if in case this doesn't work?

Comment: Just call web services of sharepoint and be independent from dlls.

Comment: See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms544240%28v=office.14%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What kind of solution are you developing?

If you want a server-side solution you will need a SharePoint farm to debug and test it anyway.
Maybe you could just reference SharePoint dlls on the local machine and compile the project (I never tried this), but you will probably face some strange errors deploying it later).
As an option you can create a virtual machine, install there Windows Server and SharePoint in standalone mode for development purposes.

If you want an independent application that will communicate with SharePoint, check out using the [Client Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee537247%28v=office.14%29.aspx). It doesn't depend on any SharePoint libraries.

As an alternative you can consume [SharePoint Web services](http://blog.crsw.com/sharepoint/index-of-sharepoint-web-services/) manually.